# linux - Seach and delete records where 2nd column starts with

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

> **"2017-09-04","D","0015","1","0015","08080000",60371,18923315.66**

This is a sample record in my file abc from which I want to delete all records which are starting with 02 like -

> "02080000"
>   "02100000"

Etc... ( Please consider " at this column start ) , I tried awk but its not working on my Linux -

**awk  -F"," '$6 != /^"02/' abc > abc_correct**

Answer (score 1):

Change `!=`  to `!~`

The two operators, `~` and `!~`, perform regular expression comparisons

```
awk -F"," '$2 !~ /^"02/' infile >outfile
```

For 6th column

```
awk -F"," '$6 !~ /^"02/' infile >outfile
```

**May be  useful:**

> Comparison operators in Awk are used to compare the value of numbers
>   or strings and they include the following:
>
> - `>` – greater than
> - `<` – less than
> - `>=` – greater than or equal to
> - `<=` – less than or equal to
> - `==` – equal to
> - `!=` – not equal to
> - `some_value ~ /regexp/` – true if some_value matches regexp
> - `some_value !~ /regexp/` – true if some_value does not match regexp

Comment: Thanks @3161993 , It worked !

What if I want to club more than one Regexp while searching ? I tried few options and these piece of codes are not working for me -
`awk  -F"," '$6 !~ /"02*&&"03*&&"07*/' myfile > myfile2`  <br/>
`awk  -F"," '$6 !~ /"02*/ || /"03*/ || /"07*/' myfile > myfile2`  <br/>
`awk  -F"," '$6 !~ /"02*|"03*|"07*' myfile > myfile2`

Comment: `awk '$6 !~ /regexp1/ && $6 !~ /regexp2/' youfile` you can club with `&&` operator, or even in your case `awk -F, '$6 !~ /"0(2|3|7)/' file`   please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can remove lines with `02` on positions 2 and 3 with

```
grep -vE '^.02 abc
```

`v` - skip lines
`E` - Expressions
`^` - start of line
`.` - any character